# Difference Django DB models using the ForeignKey to object with or without "to" statement?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and trying to understand someone else code. Where I am struggling with is the models.py and when to use a direct assignment of another object or when to use the "to" statement.

What is the difference between those statement?

```
model = models.ForeignKey('Car', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

model = models.ForeignKey(to='Car', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `to` is implicit for the first parameter (`'Car'`), I would omit it  but it is also acceptable to explicitly include it. So those statements are equivalent.